# visual studio 2019 can't find teams

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I can't seem to find the Teams menu on 2019 Visual Studio.

Is it hidden or maybe an add-on?

Normally it is found on the main menu at the top. I have the Professional Edition.

Comment: You mean team explorer?

Comment: Yes TFS........